# How to disable multitouch in Android in cocos2d-x 3.2

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am setting handlers for single touch in this way

```
auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
touchListener->setSwallowTouches(true);

touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(MyClass::onTouchBegan, this);
touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(MyClass::onTouchMoved, this);
touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(MyClass::onTouchEnded, this);

auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);
```

For iOS it works properly, but for Android if I touch the screen with two fingers in the same time it will call onTouchBegan twice.

How can I disable multitouch from cocos2d-x (3.2) code for Android?

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround, since cocos2d-x doesn't have an official solution for this. (using Cocos2d-x 3.2)

Since each touch has it's own ID, we just need to filter first touch ID from others.
I have achieved this in the following way:

Created layer's instance variable:

```
int _currentTouchID;
```

Initialised it with ***-1*** in layer's ***init()*** method:

```
_currentTouchID = -1;
```

In the beginign of all touch handlers I did next:

```
bool MyClass::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    if (_currentTouchID < 0) {
        _currentTouchID = touch->getID();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
    //Your code here

    return true;
}

void MyClass::onTouchMoved(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    if (_currentTouchID != touch->getID()) {
        return;
    }
    //Your code here
}

void MyClass::onTouchEnded(cocos2d::Touch *touch, cocos2d::Event *event)
{
    if (_currentTouchID == touch->getID()) { 
        _currentTouchID = -1; 
    }
    else { 
        return; 
    }
    //Your code here
}
```

That's it. Please provide your solution if you have found a better one.

BTW: Commenting the switch case  MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: in Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView.java file,
as it was offered on cocos2d-x forum, didn't work for me.